# Is there any Firefox extension which allow you to add a few lines of description for different websites which get shown when you revisit the website?

Tags: firefox, note-taking

I watch & rewatch a lot of youtube tutorials on my desktop. I find the 2-3 line description of each youtube video written by the creator to be inadequate in most cases. I would like add my own 3-4 lines of description to each youtube video. As soon as I revisit the video URL, my earlier notes should automatically be visible on the page.

Is there any Firefox extension which lets me do this? It need not even be an extension specific to Youtube. A general extension which allows me to add a few lines of annotation/description for any URL would be enough.